# how to install certificate in browser settings using command prompt?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, installation, certificate

I have added the certificate successfully using command prompt(example below). But I could not found the same certificate in chrome browser settings("Setting/HTTPS/SSL/Manage certificates/"), in all tabs.

How to install the certificate in browser settings ("settings/"HTTP/SSL/Manage certificates/") via command prompt? Am using "windows xp"

**import certificate:--**
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool" -import -keystore cacerts -file test.cer

Answer (score 15):

According to this blog post it sounds like the technique is identical for Chrome as well, "[Adding SSL certificates to Google Chrome Linux (Ubuntu)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910124918/http://blog.avirtualhome.com/adding-ssl-certificates-to-google-chrome-linux-ubuntu)". The directions from that post were specific to Ubuntu but should be easily adapted to other Linux variants.

**NOTE:** Much of the contents below was excerpted from this article!

#### 1. Add Software

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnss3-tools
$ sudo apt-get install curl
```

#### 2. Adding CAcert certificates

```
$ curl -k -o "cacert-root.crt" "http://www.cacert.org/certs/root.crt"
$ curl -k -o "cacert-class3.crt" "http://www.cacert.org/certs/class3.crt"
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t TC -n "CAcert.org" -i cacert-root.crt 
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t TC -n "CAcert.org Class 3" -i cacert-class3.crt
```

#### 3. Create script

This will download and import the certificate into the certificate DB. We're calling the script: `import-cert.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# usage:  import-cert.sh remote.host.name [port]
#
REMHOST=$1
REMPORT=${2:-443}
exec 6>&1
exec > $REMHOST
echo | openssl s_client -connect ${REMHOST}:${REMPORT} 2>&1 |sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t TC -n "$REMHOST" -i $REMHOST 
exec 1>&6 6>&-
```

#### 4. Adding certs

You can now run this script like so.

1. To add a certificate from a site you type the following:

   ```
   $ import-cert.sh dirae.lunarservers.com 2083
   ```

   In this case it uses port 2083 instead of the default port 443. If it’s the default port you don’t have to include the port.
2. To see which certificates are included your database:

   ```
   $ certutil -L -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb
   ```
3. And should you want to delete a certificate

   ```
   $ certutil -D -n  -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb
   ```

#### References

- [LinuxCertManagement - Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/lkgr/docs/linux/cert_management.md)

Comment: As both links have rotten, I really appreciate you taking time and writing an excerpt! Very thoughtful of you! :bow:

Comment: @Seagull - ty I updated both w/ replacements, one of them I had to reach back into wayback to get it.